# MySQL select rows between two time values which are in json format

Tags: mysql, json, select, between

I have a MySQL log table which have a column with json string. The json string contains year, month, date, hour, minutes etc. and it is automatically inserted as logs.

The sample table format is,

```
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|logId  | log                                                                           |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+   
|   1   | { "Year": "2015", "Month": "04", Date": "24", "Hour": "01", "Minute": "00" }  |
|   2   | { "Year": "2015", "Month": "04", Date": "24", "Hour": "01", "Minute": "30" }  |
|   3   | { "Year": "2015", "Month": "04", Date": "24", "Hour": "02", "Minute": "00" }  |
|   4   | { "Year": "2015", "Month": "04", Date": "24", "Hour": "02", "Minute": "30" }  |
|   5   | { "Year": "2015", "Month": "04", Date": "24", "Hour": "03", "Minute": "00" }  |
|   6   | { "Year": "2015", "Month": "04", Date": "24", "Hour": "03", "Minute": "30" }  |
|   7   | { "Year": "2015", "Month": "04", Date": "24", "Hour": "04", "Minute": "00" }  |
|   8   | { "Year": "2015", "Month": "04", Date": "24", "Hour": "04", "Minute": "30" }  |
|   .   | .                                                                             |
|   .   | .                                                                         |
|   .   | .                                                                         |
|   .   | .                                                                             |
|   .   | { "Year": "2015", "Month": "04", Date": "24", "Hour": "23", "Minute": "00" }  |
|   .   | { "Year": "2015", "Month": "04", Date": "24", "Hour": "23", "Minute": "30" }  |
|   .   | { "Year": "2015", "Month": "04", Date": "25", "Hour": "00", "Minute": "00" }  |
|   .   | { "Year": "2015", "Month": "04", Date": "25", "Hour": "00", "Minute": "30" }  |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now how can i select the rows between `02 Hrs and 30 mins` and `23 Hrs and 00 mins` of each day and a particular day?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select * from tablename where log 
not exists(select 1 from tablename where 
       log like '%"Hour": "01", "Minute": "00"%'
    or log like '%"Hour": "01", "Minute": "30"%' 
    or log like '%"Hour": "02", "Minute": "00"%' 
    or log like '%"Hour": "23", "Minute": "30"%' 
    or log like '%"Hour": "00", "Minute": "00"%' 
    or log like '%"Hour": "00", "Minute": "30"%' )
```